# 403 error in .net core mvc web hook endpoint requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

After the payment process, the stripe web hook endpoint is triggered, but I get a 403 forbidden error.

How can I allow requests from Stripe API to some IP addresses in .Net Core MVC?

Note: stripe ip addresses are available.

```
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AfterPayment()
        {
            const string endpointSecret = "whsec*****************";
                
            var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            try
            {
                var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
                    Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], endpointSecret);

                // Handle the event
                if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionAsyncPaymentSucceeded)
                {
                     //processs
                }
```

So in short, I want to allow requests from stripe api.

Yes, there is no problem in the code right now, but when Stripe API tries to trigger the webhook, I get a 403 forbidden error. I allowed the IP addresses of the APIs of the strip on the server from the IIS settings. The 403 forbidden error still persists.

For example, in classic asp.net mvc, certain IPs are allowed to send requests as follows. How can I do this in .net core mvc?

```
<system.web>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity>
            <add ipAddress="x.x.x.x" allowed="true" />
            <!-- other ip address add -->
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.web>
```

> stripe document 403 error The destination server can’t or won’t
> process the request. This might occur when the server detects an error
> (400), when the destination URL has access restrictions, (401, 403),
> or when the destination URL doesn’t exist (404).

[Server error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOLm7.png)

Comment: Is your endpoint code getting triggered at all when an event is sent to your server? If so, does a certain line in your endpoint code throw an error that causes this 403?

Comment: No, the method does not trigger.try to trigger it in the log but I see it returns 403 forbidden.I allowed the IP addresses of the strip on the server. However, I think I need to give them in the code as well.

Comment: AFAICT none of the code shown may produce a `403 Forbidden` response. There must be something else going on that we can't see. Please edit the question so that it provides a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MarkSeemann Could you please review again? When I send a request to the webhook myself via an API, it is triggered, but when the strip trigger is tried, a 403 forbidden error is returned.

Comment: Based on the information currently available, I have nothing to suggest.

Comment: If your code is not getting triggered, this issue could be any number of things on the way to your server. To clarify on what the Stripe doc you quoted is saying, this error is not coming from Stripe, it is the network error that you are sending back to Stripe. So debugging this will likely mean looking at your network configuration and code.

Comment: If you are testing with a local listener with the Stripe CLI, you will want to double check that the localhost port that Stripe is forwarding to is the same as the one your local server is listening to https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#local-listener

Comment: If you are using a webhook endpoint that you set up in your dashboard. I'd suggest looking for web traffic from the IPs that Stripe sends webhook information from. You may need to reach out to your hosting provider to do this and to double check that access to those IPs is not blocked https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications

Comment: How is the method AfterPayment protected? Does it use security restriction? Just as a test, try to add [AllowAnonymous] attribute to the AfterPayment method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I had done everything you said before. I had also allowed stripe IP addresses to be requested on the server, and I had not done any authorization in my code that would return a 403.

The reason for the error is completely related to the server. The agent information matched a rule set by which we blocked malicious bots on the server. I updated the rule according to the agent information received. There was a problem with Regex matching. Once this problem was fixed, the problem disappeared.